# Expose Traefik dashboard to subdomain

Tags: docker, cloudflare, traefik

I've got a Traefix set up and I'm trying to expose a dashboard to a website served through Cloudflare with SSL. I've combed through the docs and I can't for the life of me figure out how to expose the docs to a subdomain of one of my sites. I've got the following docker-compose file:

```
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: "traefik"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`foo.bar.dev`) && PathPrefix(`/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=dashboard@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=dashboard_redirect@internal,dashboard_stripprefix@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.priority=2"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`foo.bar.dev`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.priority=1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=dashboard_redirect@internal,dashboard_stripprefix@internal"

    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - 443
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
version: "3.3"
```

and the following traefik.toml file:

```
[accessLog]

[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

[providers.docker]
  exposedByDefault = false

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
```

I still get a 404 on the subdomain. The certificates are arranged by cloudflare so I land on port 443 in my network without any problems. My port is then forwarded by my routers to my Traefix server. I feel like the host rule is not being triggered because when I access port 8080 directly from the IP in the internal network I can access the dashboard and see the two rules set in docker.

Anybody  who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it work with the following configuration:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: "traefik"
    networks:
      - webgateway
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`foo.bar.dev`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls"
      - "traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

```
[log]
  level = "DEBUG"

[accessLog]

[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

[providers.docker]
  exposedByDefault = false

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
```

Comment: You can explain the difference: which label fixed your issue.